# ¿Como hacer que el usuario elija los colores de la página web a su gusto desde configuración de usuario y aplicarlo a todo?

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un archivo App.js que llama a distintos componentes y estos a su vez a otros. Yo quiero que desde 'configuración de usuario', dicho usuario, cambie del modo oscuro a claro toda la aplicación y que además pueda cambiar un color específico de otros componentes, como los menús. No tengo archivos html en todo el proyecto, van en los return de los componentes js. Mi estructura de archivos del app sería:

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import _VER_Home from './components/Views/_VER_Home';
    import _VER_FarmsList from './components/Views/_VER_FarmsList';
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
    import _VER_Map from './components/Views/_VER_Map';
    import Error404 from './components/Misc/Others/Error404'
    import SideBar from './components/Misc/Menus/SideBar';
    import SearchBar from './components/Misc/Menus/SearchBar';
    import _VER_WindFarmData from './components/Views/_VER_WindFarmData';
    import './App.css';
    import './Theme.css'
    import LoadingSpinner from './components/Misc/Others/LoadingSpinner';
    import _VER_WTG from './components/Views/_VER_WTG';
    import Login from './components/Login/Login';
    import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    
    var token;
    function takeToken() {
      token = sessionStorage.getItem("token");
    }
    function App() {
    
      takeToken();
      if (!token) {
        return <Login />
      }
    
      return (
    <div id="app_container_page" className="container-auto" >
      <div id='search-bar'>
        <center>
          <SearchBar />
        </center>
      </div>
      <div id='div-side-bar'>
        <SideBar />
      </div>
      <div id='site-main'>
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            {/*<Route exact path='/' element={<Login />} />*/}
            <Route exact path='/' element={<_VER_Home />} />
            <Route exact path='/portfolio' element={<_VER_FarmsList />} />
            <Route exact path='/WindFarm/:id/' element={<_VER_WindFarmData />} />
            <Route exact path='/WindFarm/:id/turbine/:turbine' element={<_VER_WTG />} />
            <Route exact path='/Map' element={<_VER_Map />} />
            <Route exact path='/Loading' element={<LoadingSpinner />} />
            <Route path='*' exact={true} element={<Error404 />} />
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </div>
    </div>

  );
}


export default App;
```

Donde SearchBar contiene el icono del usuario, que a su vez despliega una lista y al darle a configuración abre un popup, y desde ahí quiero que el usuario cambie al modo claro o oscuro y elija el color que  van a tener ciertos componentes y textos.
Pues no sé como puedo pasar esos colores al resto de componentes de react con js.

Comment: debes hacer una funcion y para capturar eventos agregas un `onClick={change_color}`  donde quieres que se aplique!

Comment: aqui tienes un buen tutorial lal respecto: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fMoD8OEYZsA

Comment: @Bryro el onClick lo tengo, mi problema es aplicar los colores en la aplicación.

Comment: @HernánGarcia gracias, lo voy a ver :D